# Why is $\frac{dz\wedge d\bar{z}}{2\pi i(1+|z|^2)^2} = \frac{-2rdr\wedge dt}{(1+r^2)^2}$ over $\mathbb C$ in polar coordinates?

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, complex-geometry

I am reading a book on vector bundles which requires me to evaluate an integration as follows:

Consider the (1,1)-form $\gamma=\frac{dz\wedge d\bar{z}}{2\pi i(1+|z|^2)^2}$ on $\mathbb C$. I want to find the value of its integration over $\mathbb C$. 
The author says that using the polar coordinate $(r,t)$ defined by $z=e^{2\pi i t}$, we can write

$\gamma=\frac{-2rdr\wedge dt}{(1+r^2)^2}$

But I can't see how the last statement is true. Iam having difficulty to make the transition of $\gamma$ from the previous coordinate to this new coordinate.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $z = re^{2\pi it}$, then $|z|^{2} = r^{2}$ and
\begin{align*}
  dz &= e^{2\pi it} (dr + 2\pi i r\, dt), \\
  d\bar{z} &= e^{-2\pi it} (dr - 2\pi i r\, dt), \\
  dz \wedge d\bar{z}
  &= (dr + 2\pi i r\, dt) \wedge (dr - 2\pi i r\, dt)
  = -2(2\pi i r)\, dr \wedge dt,
\end{align*}
or
$$
\frac{dz \wedge d\bar{z}}{2\pi i} = -2r\, dr \wedge dt.
$$
Substituting,
$$
\gamma = \frac{dz \wedge d\bar{z}}{2\pi i (1 + |z|^{2})^{2}}
= -\frac{2r\, dr \wedge dt}{(1 + r^{2})^{2}}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. At first I could not figure out your second and third line, as that was precisely where I was getting confused, but then taking $z=x+iy$ and doing some computation I got it.

Comment: Writing $z = x + iy$ is more work than necessary: Just take $d(re^{2\pi i t})$, treating $r$ and $t$ as coordinates. :)